# My carousel code isn't working :/ (next and prev button) (bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

This is my carousel code.

Indicators are working fine, 
but "next" and "prev" `button`s aren't responding.

My scripts are:

- popperjs,
- bootstrap-5.2.0
- jquery-3.6.0.

The links in my `<head>` HTML element.

and scripsts are in the body.

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">

    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/ecg.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/tech.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/tecnical.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/ultrason.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>


    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="mycarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visially-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="mycarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visially-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: In the bootstrap docs, there is a ```<script>``` tag that usually goes at the end of the ```<body>``` tag. Did you add that also? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I've already used them. I mentioned above. :)

Comment: try to include it at the end of the body tag because in your post it says it is in your ```<head>``` tag and the ```<script>``` shouldn't be there it should be at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMpSO.png)

my carousel code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">

        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"
                aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            <button data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
        </div>
    
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visially-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visially-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).